# Restriction of a function in Bochner space

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, lebesgue-integral, lp-spaces, bochner-spaces

I'm starting to work with evolution PDEs and I'm still a little bit unfamiliar with Bochner spaces. I will ask my concrete question, but probably I might be missing some nuances that I will have to learn along the way.

Consider the following [paper](https://www.intlpress.com/site/pub/files/_fulltext/journals/mrl/2005/0012/0002/MRL-2005-0012-0002-a005.pdf) by Ionescu and Kenig in which they prove a certain well-posedness result for the initial value problem for the Schrödinger equation
$$(i\partial_t+\Delta)u=Vu \quad \textrm{in }\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}^n,$$
$$u(0,\centerdot)=f\quad \textrm{in }\mathbb{R}^n.$$
Here, $V$ is a potential with certain degree of regularity. The thing is, Theorem 1 in the paper says the solution $u(t,x)$ lays in the space $B= C([0,T],L^2(\mathbb{R}^n))\cap L_t^2L_x^{p_n}$, where $p_n$ is the endpoint index for the $H^1$-Hardy-Littlewood-Sobolev embedding, i.e. $1/p_n=1/2-1/n$, and the map $f\mapsto u$ is bounded from $L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$ to $B$.

This boundedness implies also (which is actually very classical) that the map $f\mapsto u(T,\centerdot)$ is bounded from $L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$ to $L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$. In this case, this map is just the composition of the map $f\mapsto u$ with restriction to $t=T$.

I would like to say that $f\mapsto u(T,\centerdot)$ is also bounded from $L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$ to $L^{p_n}(\mathbb{R}^n)$. Unfortunately the restriction to $t=T$ does not need to even make in principle, since here we are time-wise in $L^2([0,T])$. However, such restriction does exist as a function, by the paragraph above, so we are left to prove boundedness. Do you have any ideas on how to approach it?

Comment: I would expect that this map is not bounded (without further properties of the solution). From what you  wrote, it is bounded from $L^2$ to $L^2$, upgrading this to boundedness from $L^2$ to $L^{p_n}$ seems not possible without knowing more about the behavior of $u$ with respect to $t$.

Comment: Thank you, that's what I thought. It is not only that the map isn't bounded, but that we can't even assert that  the restriction to any given time belongs to $L^{p_n}$, can we?

Comment: Yes, that is not even well-defined. Still there is a chance to get the result, provided some extra regularity of $u$ is found.